# Using hidden and open keys for data tables

Tags: database

Not a coding question per se. just trying to get some best practices suggestions.

I believe it is best practice to have a key for every data table. I've read recently that a key should NOT be an integer (auto number, etc.) because it makes hacking a slight bit easier.
So, I've started to use Guid for keys.
Now, should I use a human-readable ID as well?
Example, for a table of departments in an organization: Human Resources, Information Technology, etc. should I also include a column for the ID such as HR, IT, etc.
What are your thoughts?

PS. I realize this is a simple example for discussion sake. Thanks

Comment: I work with data a lot and for transferring data to other databases a GUID is best. It's always unique, so you never get the issue of 2 customers/employees having the same Badge-ID, say Badge nr. '234' and that giving a transfer error. For human readability and remembering someones ID, a short number is best. Like department nr. 7 or building nr. 4. So I use them both. GUID for computers/systems and short ID's for my colleagues. Almomst forgot the auto-increment ID's in a Database, they are just a row-number to me and never use them actively...

Comment: @MikedeBie Post this as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks, John